# model class is not working in laravel project

Tags: laravel-5.5

i am beginner in la-ravel,problem in work on **model** how be work on project.

```
firstly used the api.php to link the page
 Route::any('/user',['uses'=>'PagesController@my']);
```

create the controller

```
public function my(Request $request){
    $val=validator::make($request->all(),[
        'id'=>'required',
        'name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required',
        'mobile'=>'required'
    ]);
    //return 'rahul';
    return response()->json([$val]);
}
```

model is link to the controller

```
use App\rahul;
use Validator;
```

create the model page design

```
class rahul extends Model{
protected $table = "display";
public function my($data)
{
     $save = new rahul;
    $save->id = $data['id'];
    $save->name = $data['name'];
    $save->email = $data['email'];
    $save->mobile = $data['mobile'];
    $save->save();
    return $save->id;       

}
```

}

and,last step will done it create the database like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnCHk.png)
database name is lara2 and table name display simple page design

but problem how to model be used

Comment: You need to give more clarity to your question

Comment: how to design the model to connect the database in project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('first', 'ApiController@first')->name('first');
Route::post('store', 'ApiController@store')->name('store');
```

using the code in api.php
and next step model is create

```
php artisan make: model Article
```

**model page**

```
class Article extends Model{ protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];}
```

next step create the controller
**controller page (apicontroller)**

```
public function first(){
    return view('first');
}

   public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $article = Article::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($article, 201); 
 }
```

**blade page web page design**

```
<form method="POST" action="store">
{{csrf_field()}}
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit"></form>
```

migration is create **Article** table name connection

```
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('Articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
         $table->timestamps();
    });

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
            Schema::dropIfExists('Articles');
}
```